# Minimal example of doing PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256 + AES/GCM/NoPadding throwing: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: mac check in GCM failed

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

I wrote this minimal example of encrypting and decrypting in Java, using Bouncy Castle, PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256 to derive the key from the password and AES/GCM/NoPadding to encrypt/verify the payload:

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;
import tech.dashman.dashman.crypto.Util;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);

        String password = "password";
        String payload = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in tincidunt metus. Nam nec diam sed velit blandit porta quis et augue. Praesent imperdiet, nulla vel aliquam porta, dui nisi dictum justo, pellentesque elementum purus orci at leo. Duis scelerisque, urna sit amet fringilla interdum, mauris felis sagittis eros, eleifend tincidunt risus nulla ut erat. Aliquam id sapien non neque rutrum lacinia at vitae lorem. Vivamus quis ligula nunc. Aenean facilisis pretium leo, vitae gravida quam ultrices et. Ut venenatis eros in justo semper fermentum. Pellentesque convallis lectus urna, fringilla rhoncus metus faucibus quis. Sed eu rhoncus tortor. Donec lacinia tempor elementum.";

        int keyLength = 256;
        int saltLength = keyLength / 8; // It's bytes, not bits.
        int iterations = 65536;

        byte[] salt = new SecureRandom().generateSeed(saltLength);
        PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, keyLength);
        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256", "BC");
        SecretKey passwordKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding", "BC");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, passwordKey);
        byte[] iv = cipher.getIV();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cipher.getIV()));
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(payload.getBytes());

        System.out.println(Base64.toBase64String(cipherText));

        keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, keyLength);
        secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256", "BC");
        passwordKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);

        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding", "BC");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, passwordKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cipher.getIV()));
        byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(payload.getBytes());
        System.out.println(new String(plainText));
    }
}
```

But it's not working. I'm getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: mac check in GCM failed
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher$AEADGenericBlockCipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
    at tech.dashman.dashman.Scratch.main(Scratch.java:51)
```

I've verified, just in case, that the init vector is the same on both ciphers. What else am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re trying to decrypt the plaintext instead of the cipher text. The second to last line:

```
byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(payload.getBytes());
```

should be:

```
byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
```